# Returning value from a async call in node module

Tags: node.js, module, async-await, es6-promise

I am working on a vue app and have written a module that uses axios to make a call to mySportsFeed.com to get data. My problem is that due to the async nature of axios I am getting a promise returned instead of the data. I have tried several different ways to solve this problem to no avail. I'm hoping someone will be able to point out my error. The code is:

vue.js

```
//====== Get Standings From MySportsFeeds Site ======================================== //
  url = `https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.2/pull/mlb/2018-regular/division_team_standings.json?teamstats=W,L,GB,Win %`;

  mySportsFeeds.feedsData(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      this.standings = response;
      console.log(`Standings is : ${this.standings}`);
  });

  // ======= end Standings ================================================ //
```

mySportsFeeds.js:

```
    module.exports = {
  /* jshint ignore:start */
  feedsData: async function(url) {
    url = encodeURI(url); // Format the URI

    return (await axios.get(url, config)).data.divisionteamstandings.division;
  }
```

And the console output:

Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]               mySportsFeeds.js:29

Standings is : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] vue.js:106

And the vue panel shows :
standings: Array [0]

[image: Console Output]

As you see this.standings is undefined? Any guidance much appreciated....

Updated working code:
vue.js:

```
 //====== Get Standings From MySportsFeeds Site =========================== //
      url = `https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.2/pull/mlb/2018-regular/division_team_standings.json?teamstats=W,L,GB,Win %`;

      /* jshint ignore:start */
      // Note: We use the arrow function here because "this" is defined by where
      // getStandings() is called (the vue instance) not by where it is used.
      let getStandings = async () => {
        this.standings = await mySportsFeeds.feedsData(url);
      };
      /* jshint ignore:end */

      getStandings();
```

mySportsFeeds.js:

```
module.exports = {
  /* jshint ignore:start */
  feedsData: async function(url) {
    url = encodeURI(url); // Format the URI

    return (await axios.get(url, config)).data.divisionteamstandings.division;
  }
  /* jshint ignore:end */
};
```

Comment: You need to make everything async and use promises everywhere.

Comment: More importantly, you need to make your function actually return something.

Comment: If you're using `await`, there is no point in using `then()`.

Comment: I thought my function is returning variable data?

Comment: No, there is no `return` statement inside `feedsData` itself. You want something like `return (await axios.get(url, config)).data.divisionteamstandings.division;`

Comment: I'm sorry could you be a more specific. I should use async both in vue.js and mySportsfeeds.js? And how to get the response from axios if no .then used?

Comment: *"how to get the response from axios if no .then used?"* See the edit to my comment. `foo().then(data => /*do something with data*/)` is equivalent to `var data = await foo(); /* do something with data*/`.

Comment: See updated mySportsFeed.js I seem to be returning something but the Vue panel shows standings as an array[0].

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes you're right it is the Windows object. Yet I use this to assign other Vue instance data properties in same function and it worked fine. Any ideas .thanks..

Comment: Are you sure `(await axios.get(url, config)).data.divisionteamstandings.division` is defined?

Comment: to make it work: `return axios.get(url, config)`. In `then()` block do `.then(response => console.log(response))` and post here what it outputs

Comment: Thanks everyone see updated code it now works. Any suggestions for refactoring welcomed...